# Multiple public RESTful Web services

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, apexrest

I need to set up multiple public RESTful web services as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html). However, I cannot get the rest services to work unless I leave the `Default Web Address` option blank. I would like to have these multiple services under different sites so they can have different permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am going to take a stab at this. After your domain if you add a `Default Web Address` you are branching away from where the `/services/apexrest/` lives. So you are already in deeper than the services folder. Again, just a guess here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you associate an @RestResource endpoint with a site, the URL to access that service includes the suffix specified in the site "Default Web Address".

So with a suffix of "abc" this endpoint:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/something')
global with sharing class SomethingService {
   @HttpGet  
   global static ...
```

is available at:

```
/abc/services/apexrest/something
```

Providing you always have the suffix defined, this allows you to have multiple sites that have distinct endpoints, including when the same @RestResource class is used in more than one site.